# It is possible to async a local_action in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible to provision vagrant machines. Now I want the playbook to uncompress the database dump, import it in the vm and then recompress it back.

In "normal" mode this is not a big deal, but since my dumps can be pretty big the uncompress/compress operation take lots of time. I would like to use the "fire and forget" method described here https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_async.html

The idea is:

1. "fire and forget" the dump bunzip
2. [ do all the other operations like package install, configurations ecc]
3. get back to the bunzip
4. import dump
5. fire and forget dump recompression

If I attempt to bunzip using a `local_action` it dies with `ERROR: unexpected error: unable to determine jid`

It is possible to do an async local task?

**Edit**

Tasks list example

```
# start async unzip
- name: bunzip dump
    command: bunzip2 /vagrant/vagrant_provision/dump.sql.bz2
    async: 10000
    poll: 0
    register: bunzip_status

#[... do other things ...]

# connect back to unzip and wait for it to end
- name: Check for dump bunzip
    async_status: jid={{ bunzip_status.ansible_job_id }}
    register: bunzip_result
    until: bunzip_result.finished
    retries: 80

#[... Import db ...]

# Fire and forget dump recompression
  - name: Recompress dump
    command: bzip2 /vagrant/vagrant_provision/dump.sql
    async: 10000
    poll: 0
```

Now.. since I'm using this to provision a vagrant environment I partially solved by putting my playbook and files inside the vagrant shared folder and referencing them by absolute path, and it works.

But the question is: It is possible to async a `local_action` (or even simply a `delegate_to`)?

In this case the use of `local_action` instead to do the archive/unarchive remotely allows me to use all my cpus (4 versus 1 assigned to vm) to do those operations and that I can even shutdown the vm during the final recompression without having to wait for it to finish.

Comment: Why would you bunzip local_action instead of using `unarchive` module which will uncompress your file into the destination server? Using it you won't have to recompress it afterwards.

Comment: @Mxx I tried to async the `unarchive` module but get an error, so tried with command. For me is quite the same to use `unarchive` or `command bunzip`. The only issue is that I'm very short of disk space and unarchive creates another file while bzip (at the end of process) leaves only one.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten to the point where I make use of [gnu screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) whenever I want to background/async a command in Ansible so that I can verify that the command is running properly.

Given what you're describing you'd need to come up with a way to notify Ansible when you've reached step #3.  To do that you'd probably want to create a temporary flag file that Ansible can look for.  So to do what you describe I'd probably do something along these lines:

First, I'd create a wrapper script to unbzip the file just to make things a bit cleaner.  It would create the flag file that I mentioned when the bunzip is complete.  Here's a bare-bones example:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /tmp/bunzip.done
bunzip /path/to/file.bz2
touch /tmp/bunzip.done
exit
```

Then I'd then execute this from within Ansible in a screen session like this (I use sudo in this example since I also typically sudo my screen sessions to a specific user):

```
- name: invoke bunzip script
  local_action: command /usr/bin/screen -d -m sudo -u someuser /path/to/bzip_script.sh
  async: True
  poll: 0
```

At this point you can do whatever you need to do within Ansible. Once you get to step #3 then you would want to do something like this:

```
- name: wait for bunzip if it is still running
  local_action: wait_for path=/tmp/bunzip.done state=present
```

As long as the wait_for script returns without error you should be able to safely reference the bunzipped data at this point. wait_for defaults to a 300 second timeout, so you may need to increase that if you expect bunzip to take longer.

Comment: Did you know Ansible has `async_status` module to check on async tasks?

Comment: I never tought about using screen to have a look to what is happening, and it's a clever idea that can turn useful, especially when testing playbooks... but it doesn't seem to me the "ansible way" to do things. I'd prefer to know the use of the tool as it was conceived.